# What rights do I have as an American citizen when major social websites censor certain news stories or other public opinions?

Tags: united-states, social-media, first-amendment

Are we not entitled as American citizens to expect U.S. based social web empires like Twitter, Instagram, Facebook, YouTube, etc., to let us determine for ourselves what is factual and what is not as we consume content over the web? Conversely, are American content providers and private citizens on social media not entitled to free speech and free press on these platforms?

These two questions are tightly coupled so I've dared to ask them together in one post.

I can certainly agree that allowing video on YouTube displaying a man's execution is very distasteful and inappropriate for public audiences, and that dangerous bomb-making instructions ought not be generally disseminated over public venues like Wikipedia.

But simple differences of opinion in regards to government and public policy are frequently being censored lately right in front of our eyes over these channels. It could be a potential conspiracy theory  for all I care! Is it constitutional for Silicon Valley's own Facebook to censor a post and chalk it up to "independent fact-checking"? What I see happening here instead is that this social channel is actively crushing dissent.

Here's [a sample of censored video journalism](https://www.facebook.com/1151307804/posts/10222817357039768/?d=n) someone posted recently on Facebook (whose content I don't wish to promote, so I've blurred it). Just as I came to watch it, the video stream was shut off on account that it was supposedly, "Partly False". Today, you try to visit the link and it won't even appear. There was nothing violent in it, and nothing explicitly sexual. It was simply an interview with a controversial figure about a controversial subject. Yet this was censored:
[image]

Is all this social media censorship a violation of our constitutional rights or not?

Comment: No. These platforms are private businesses, not government entities bound to the Constitution. They can and do choose what you access.

Comment: Almost a duplicate of https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/39731/freedom-of-speech-and-where-it-applies which asked the same thing about the social media companies, but with references to the freedom of speech in UN human rights declarations, rather than the US constitution. And the funny version https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/10817/wikipedia-context-and-freedom-of-speech/

Comment: Also https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/26564/has-facebook-s-or-other-social-network-block-policy-been-abused-to-limit-freed And probably more closely related: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/39046/why-is-facebook-not-restricted-by-the-u-s-government-to-be-politically-neutral although the latter question asks why the major social media companies aren't legally restricted in their (apparent) political bias.

Comment: Actually, I think that q is close enough esp. wrt answers (which insist on the gov't/private distinction in US law, so I'm using my "gold hammer" to close this as a dupe (there are 3 close votes already, albeit for different reasons.) Actually, my gold hammer didn't work, because I've edited the question (to properly add the US tag.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is Facebook not restricted by the U.S. government to be politically neutral, like the U.S. Army, for example?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/39046/why-is-facebook-not-restricted-by-the-u-s-government-to-be-politically-neutral)

Comment: Nobody has mentioned this yet, so I might as well do it: you might get better answers on Law.SE, as while the US Constitution is political, the rights guaranteed in it from a legal perspective might be better answered by lawyers.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's answers. I just want to clear up that I very consciously tried not to, "promote or discredit a specific political cause, group or politician," as those who closed it claimed. I *never* identified any "cause, group or politician" in my question and tried to keep the topic as abstract and neutral as possible. That said, I understand better now that these private social media channels have a right of their own to permit what they will to be published on their pages. And I have a right to go look elsewhere. However, this is surely a potential for media monopoly/oligopoly.

Comment: I think this is a worthy followup: President Donald Trump's "executive order calls for new regulations under Section 230 of the Communications Decency Act to make it that social media companies that engage in censoring or any political conduct will not be able to keep their liability shield." (https://www.foxbusiness.com/technology/trump-social-media-companies-alleged-bias)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trivial answer is "none".  As other answers have noted, corporate social media is not the US Government.  The US Government usually has no statutory power *within* [corporate media](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corporate_media) to either prevent corporate censorship or compel corporate editing.

However, this easily answered question implies a thornier one:  if ever a handful of large and powerful multinational corporations should hold a *de facto* virtual [media monopoly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ben_Bagdikian#The_Media_Monopoly) or actual [media oligopoly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentration_of_media_ownership) over the means of public communication, the results could at worst be all too similar to government censorship, but without any of the accountability typical of a democratic society.

That is, if we imagine for the sake of argument that the USA appointed an "Official Media Censor" who abused their office, aggrieved citizens might "vote the bums out" -- with corporations this option doesn't exist.

On the flip side, corporations need money, and [media corporations need eyeballs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attention_economy), so citizen consumers in a capitalistic society at least have the option of looking elsewhere, and spending their dollars on whatever smaller forms of media exist that are more to their liking.  Unlike with government censorship, buying an unpopular dissident magazine (usually) won't get the buyer thrown in jail.

Answer (score 18):

You have the right to look for other news sources.

"Free speech" is about the *government* restrictions or compulsions, and the First Amendment was originally about Congress alone.  (The Fourteenth Amendment has been interpreted as extending those First Amendment protections to cover actions by state and local governments.)

It's important to remember that "freedom of the press" includes the right to *not* publish.  Compelling someone to say something they disagree with is just as much a First Amendment violation as forbidding them to speak is.

Comment: Or even to start your own social media platform.

Answer (score 10):

> Are we not entitled as American citizens to expect U.S. based social web empires like Twitter, Instagram, Facebook, YouTube, etc., to let us determine for ourselves what is factual and what is not as we consume content over the web?

You're free to expect it, but you're going to be disappointed. That's because:

> Conversely, are American content providers and private citizens on social media not entitled to free speech and free press on these platforms?

Absolutely not. The First Amendment restricts government action, not private action. For instance, in [*Manhattan Community Access Corp v. Halleck*](https://www.supremecourt.gov/opinions/18pdf/17-1702_h315.pdf), the Supreme Court held that "The Free Speech Clause of the First Amendment constrains governmental actors and protects private actors." The Court went on to say that

> Under  this  Court’s  cases,  a  private  entity  can  qualify  as  a  state  actor  in  a  few  limited  circumstances — including,  for  example,  (i) when  the  private  entity  performs  a  traditional,  exclusive  public  function,  see,  e.g., Jackson,  419  U. S.,  at  352–354;  (ii) when  the  government  compels the private entity to take a particular action, see, e.g., Blum v. Yaretsky, 457 U. S. 991, 1004–1005 (1982); or (iii) when  the  government  acts  jointly  with  the  private  entity,  see,  e.g.,  Lugar  v. Edmondson  Oil  Co.,  457  U. S. 922, 941–942 (1982).

*Manhattan Community Access* involved a private corporation that was designated by New York City to administer public access channels as part of a franchise agreement between the city and Time Warner Cable. Public access channels were required by NY state law, and the state law heavily regulated how those channels must be operated. Local governments had a role in this: the cable operator would normally operate the public access channel, but the local government could instead decide to run it or could designate some private entity to run it.

Despite all this government involvement, the Court held that MCAC was not a state actor when deciding what to show. Running a forum for people to speak is not traditionally an exclusive state function. The dispute turned on whether the public access channel was itself city property that MCAC was running *on behalf of* the city (running a city-owned public forum on behalf of the city is considered state action), and even with such a close relationship the Supreme Court held that it was not.

Turning to private social media, it has far less connection to the government than MCAC did. MCAC was officially designated by the city to operate a channel that state law explicitly designated as a public forum. Facebook and Twitter are not. Their actions are based on their own interests; they aren't administering their sites on behalf of the government.  They are not state actors, and the First Amendment doesn't apply to them.

Answer (score 2):

As other answers pointed out, the US constitutional law clearly applies to government entities, not private sector corporations.

One might ask interesting questions about those companies trying to "have their cake and eat it, too" by claiming **both** the right to sort, alter, or suppress user content on *their own* sites, and a near-total lack of responsibility for the content generated by *their users*.

- A newspaper is free to write what they want, subject to libel laws etc. They're also responsible for what they publish.
- A telephone company is not held responsible for the content of speech over their lines. They do not control the content, either.
- A social media company claims the immunity of a telephone company with the editorial control of a newspaper.

But the situation right now is both legal and constitutional, because the Constitution was written long before the internet and laws have exceptions which treat social media platforms like telecommunication providers. Changing the US Constitution is a rather impractical proposition.

One might also ask about problems of monopolies/[oligopolies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oligopoly) in the social media market and the need to [apply anti-trust laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakup_of_the_Bell_System), but that's another can of worms.

Comment: “possibly because most laws and especially the Constitution were written long before the internet.” The law explicitly giving them immunity even if they curate their content was written in the 1990s and is *exclusively* about the Internet. Off the Internet, there’s a link between curation and liability. Online, Congress explicitly broke that link and said “you can try to keep your site from being 4chan without being liable for everything anybody posts.”